# Java joining lists depending on values,

Tags: java, list, join

Data: 
`List<List<int>> startList` - list where is populated lists of integers, inner list has mostly 2 elements like: `{[1,2], [2,3],[3,1]}`;

Task:
Need to write algorithm which will join innerLists, where last of list element equals first element of list.

Example:

```
  List<List<int>> startList = {[1,2],
                               [2,3],
                               [4,7],
                               [7,4],
                               [3,1],
                               [6,2],
                               [3,2],}
```

and result should be: `{[1,2,3,1],[1,2,3,2],[4,7,4],[6,2]}`

As for me, I can find out how to do this using several dimensions loops like:

```
while(true)
{
  ...
  for (List<String> list : startList)
  {
    ...
    for (List<String> list : startList)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

But is very bad solution, because when it is lot data (like 5000 inerLists) it will work for hours.
So maybe someone can suggest better solution?

Comment: `List<int>` ? ...You can't use primitives with `List`

Comment: There could be multiple solutions for this problem, for example - why didn't you "combine" [6,2] and [2,3] in the first iteration? Or can you "combine" only adjacent lists?

Answer (score 1):

this code snippet performs in one iteration so order is O(N). pleas try to run with your dataset and let me know if any issues.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> one = new ArrayList<Integer>();one.add(1);one.add(2);
    List<Integer> two = new ArrayList<Integer>();two.add(2);two.add(3);
    List<Integer> three = new ArrayList<Integer>();three.add(3);three.add(1);
    List<Integer> four = new ArrayList<Integer>();four.add(4);four.add(7);
    List<Integer> five = new ArrayList<Integer>();five.add(7);five.add(4);
    List<Integer> six = new ArrayList<Integer>();six.add(6);six.add(2);
    list.add(one);list.add(two);list.add(three);list.add(four);list.add(five);list.add(six);

    System.out.println(list);

    List<List<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        List<Integer> current = list.get(i);
        List<Integer> last = output.size() == 0 ? null : output.get(output.size()-1);
        if(null != last)
        {
            if(current.get(0)==last.get(last.size()-1))
            {
                last.addAll(current.subList(1, current.size()));
                output.set(output.size()-1, last);
            }
            else
            {
                output.add(current);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            output.add(current);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(output);
}
}
```

Comment: Just noticed bug, which I did not checked in begining :)
make : list.add(one);list.add(two);list.add(four);list.add(three);list.add(five);list.add(six); and it will stop working :)

Comment: how about the timings dude!! :)  did you execute this and verified ?

Comment: it worked for me !!

input ==  [[1, 2], [2, 3], [4, 7], [3, 1], [7, 4], [6, 2]]
output == [[1, 2, 3], [4, 7], [3, 1], [7, 4], [6, 2]]

oops , so is it like it cannot be consecutive as well !! okay i need to fix that

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you are looking for - at least it generates the output you stated for the test input. I hope I have interpreted your needs correctly.

I have not stopped the ring at `last == first` as that does not match your expected output. I have stopped the ring when it touches an already visited entry. See your example - your entry `[6,2]` would never reach back to `6` and so would never stop.

```
// Finds which entry in the list is the target of the specified entry.
private int findTarget(List<List<Integer>> list, int pos) {
    // Look for that value.
    int targetValue = list.get(pos).get(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).get(0) == targetValue) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private List<List<Integer>> findAllRings(List<List<Integer>> list) {
    // Maintain a BitSet to keep track of all visited nodes.
    BitSet visited = new BitSet(list.size());
    // The rings.
    List<List<Integer>> rings = new ArrayList<>();
    // Carry on until all entries have been visited.
    int start = 0;
    while (start < list.size()) {
        // Where we are in the list.
        int pos = start;
        // Grow a new ring.
        List<Integer> ring = new ArrayList<>();
        // Stop when we touch one we have already seen.
        boolean ringClosed;
        do {
            // The value to add.
            ring.add(list.get(pos).get(0));
            // Stop if it already was set.
            ringClosed = visited.get(pos);
            // Track it's visited.
            visited.set(pos);
            if (!ringClosed) {
                // Move pos.
                pos = findTarget(list, pos);
                if (pos < 0) {
                    // No next pair - break this ring.
                    ringClosed = true;
                }
            }
        } while (!ringClosed);
        // One ring!
        rings.add(ring);

        // All done - move i forward until we find an unvisited node.
        while (start < list.size() && visited.get(start)) {
            start += 1;
        }
    }
    return rings;
}

public void test() {
    List<List<Integer>> startList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2}),
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{2, 3}),
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{3, 1}),
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{4, 7}),
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{7, 4}),
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{6, 2}),
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{6, 3}),
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{9, 9})
    ));
    List<List<Integer>> resultList = findAllRings(startList);
    for (List<Integer> result : resultList) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1]
[4, 7, 4]
[6, 2]
[6, 3]
[9, 9]
```

as requested.

**Edit:** Used a `Map` to remove the need for the inner loop. We should now be approximately `O(n)`.
**Edit:** Changed usage of `BitSet` to record the offset of the pair, not the value in the first entry of the pair - stops the `BitSet` blowing up for real `int` values.
Removed the `Map` as it is no longer an optimisation.

Comment: problem of your code is that if there will be one more inner list for example  [6,3] it will ignore it, because "6" already will be prezent in "visited" Set.

Comment: @Edgar - Could you therefore restate your needs and provide further examples of what you expect. Currently my code produces the results you requested.

Comment: @Edgar - How about now? I've added `[6,3]` and made sure it outputs too.

Comment: now it works with [6,3] (as for example), is it hard to change the code in such way, that if there will be ane more innerList [3,8] output will be [1,2,3,1],[1,2,3,8],... (another output as was before), I changed my example in first post.

Comment: @Edgar - Enumerating all possible sequences like that would be significantly more complex. By all means post another question requesting that and see if anyone posts an answer.